# what does x % 2 > 0 mean in java?

Tags: java, loops, break, continue

I'm currently learning java in my online classes and I'm learning about loops (specifically continue and break statements). The example given to me was:

```
int j = 0
while (true){
    System.out.println();
    j++;
    System.out.print(j);
    if (j%2 > 0) continue
    System.out.print(" is divisible by 2");
    if (j >= 10) break;
}
```

I don't understand why its (j%2 > 0) and not (j%2 == 0) because what if 'j' is 5 for example and you do 5%2. Wouldnt the number you get be 1? Or am I missing something? Can someone please explain this to me?
(sorry is I'm not my question is a little confusing. I've never used this site before and I'm pretty young)

Comment: *Wouldnt the number you get be 1* - yes. So the value is greater than 0 and you continue. That is you don't want to display the message "...is divisible by 2" because 5 isn't.

Comment: Missing `;` after `continue`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I strongly suggest you learn to use your IDE debugger so you can step through the code one line at a time and examine variables.  That is the fastest, easiest and all-around best way to understand what programs are doing.

Comment: ah ok im starting to understand thank you everyone <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue means "go to the top of the loop, skipping the rest of the loop's code" not "continue with the code".  So since 5%2 is 1, and 1 > 0, the continue will execute, going directly to the top of the loop and skipping the rest of the body.

Why do they use > 0 instead of != 0?  There isn't any technical reason, its a style difference.  I personally would have used the latter as its more clear in my mind.  But either works.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain to you.  See the comments next to each line.

```
int j = 0          
while (true){
    System.out.println();
    j++;                   //increases the value of j on the next line by 1.
    System.out.print(j);   //prints 1, the first time because of above, 0 + 1.
    if (j%2 > 0) continue  //using modulus operator(%) we are doing 1 % 2, answer is 1
                           //since 1 % 2(if 1 is divisible by 2) > 0 we are 
                           //continue statement breaks the iteration in the 
                           //loop, so anything below this line won't be 
                           //executed.
    System.out.print(" is divisible by 2");//this line will only be executed
                                           //if j is divisible by 2. that is 
                                           //j is divisible by 2 (j%2 == 0)
    if (j >= 10) break;                    //when j is equal or greater than 
                                           //0 we are stopping the while loop.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int j = 0;
while (true){
    System.out.println();
    j++;
    System.out.print(j);
// in this case you won't print any message and you  
// are sure that the next number is even (j will be incremented by "continue;").
    if (j%2 > 0) continue; 
    System.out.print(" is divisible by 2");
    if (j >= 10) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

X % 2 means the remainder when is x is divided by 2. So if the remainder of x/2 is more than 0, it means that x is an odd number. When x%2 == 0, then x is a positive number